# Xamarin Forms - Creation of custom entry column sfdatagrid with complex data binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I currrently am working on a project where i am attempting to programmatically generate syncfusion datagrid columns and assign each column a custom template, which is simply an entry field that can be edited. I have been able to create all the fields. Each of which wasn't attached to a  major nework I also need to bind an initial value to it, which i have tried with simple labels and it seemed to work. However, when i try to run this i get the error:

> Binding: 'Distances' property not found on 'APPNAME.ViewModel', target property: 'Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.Renderers.SfEntry.Text.

It still displays the cells, but not with the correct presentation.

ContentPage:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView.FrozenColumnsCount = 1;
            dataGridView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Objects;
            dataGridView.BindingContext = viewModel.Objects;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDatapoints; i++)
            {
                var newColumn = new GridTemplateColumn()
                {
                    HeaderText = $"Distance {i + 1}",
                    MappingName = $"Distances[{i}].Distance",
                    Width = 100
                };

                Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate templateColumn = new Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    var entry = new SfEntry()
                    {
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalTextAlignment = Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Center,
                        BindingContext = viewModel
                    };
                    entry.SetBinding(SfEntry.TextProperty, $"Distances[{i}].Distance");
                    return entry;
                });

                newColumn.CellTemplate = templateColumn;

                dataGridView.Columns.Add(newColumn);
            }
        }
```

The viewmodel simply contains an observable collection of "BindingObjectTest" which is then populated.

So the data structure is:
viewmodel -> Objects (ObsLst [BindObjTst]) -> Distances (ObsLst[ObservableDistances]) -> Distance (decimal)

As i said, the solution works with labels, but I can't see why it isn't binding properly to an entry. (Im suspicious it might be to do with the Sf.Entry.TextProperty being different for the SfEntry.

If there's any more info you need please just ask :)
Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have initialized binding as viewmodel class for entry in the cell template and this is not correct way. So, remove the binding for the entry to achieve your requirement.
For more details please refer the code snippet and attached sample.

Code snippet :

GridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn
()
{
HeaderText = $"Distances{0}",
MappingName = "Distances[0].Dist",
Width = 50,
};
var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
var entry = new SfEntry()
{
HorizontalTextAlignment = Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Center,
VerticalTextAlignment = Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Center,
};
entry.SetBinding(SfEntry.TextProperty, "Distances[0].Dist");
return entry;
});
templateColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);

Sample link : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/DataGridSample13733504452029276592.zip

Regards,
Karthik Raja